# Eliminar espacio vacío en HTML

Tags: html, css

¡Hola!

Soy nuevo en la plataforma y estoy buscando ayuda en HTML. Resulta que tengo una página un poco bien hecha, pero el problema que tengo es que al usar "position:relative" en divs o imágenes el espacio vacío de esos elementos queda ahí y quisiera saber como eliminarlos, lamento si no llego a proveer algo, como dije soy nuevo, agradecería la ayuda :-]

```
<div id="Ak">
    <article id="Ac">
        <h2 id="Ad">Tipos de Tecnologías</h2>
            <p id="Ae">Podemos identificar los dos tipos principales de tecnologías:
            <br>
            <br>
            <u>Tecnologías duras:</u> Aquellas que utilizan elementos de las ciencias duras como la ingeniería, la mecánica, la matemática, la física, química y otras.  De esta forma se puede poner como ejemplo de tecnología dura, la aplicada al ámbito de la informática, de la bioquímica, de la electrónica, etc. Otra característica de estas, es que el producto que se obtiene es no sólo visible sino también tangible; es decir, que se trata de la producción de bienes materiales.
            <br>
            <br>
            <u>Tecnologías blandas:</u> Aquellas que se apoyan sobre las ciencias humanísticas o blandas, como ser la sociología, la psicología, la economía, etc. Por lo general, se las utiliza con el fin de lograr mejorías dentro de instituciones o empresas que les permitan conseguir sus objetivos de una forma más eficaz. En este caso el producto que se obtiene no es visible ni tangible, dado que consiste en la elaboración de servicios, estrategias, teorías y otros.
            </p>
    </article>
</div>

<div class="clearfix">
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="img/Tecnología.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="img/dura.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="img/Fija.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
</div>


<footer>
<h1>Footer</h1>
</footer>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es eliminar el espacio en blanco que se genera ahí, de manera que solo quede una línea divisoria pequeña pero que no quede ese enorme espacio.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Por favor sube el código de lo que estás intentando. Una imagen no es de mucha ayuda para ver el problema. Puedes leer [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] para agregar lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Sin el CSS no podemos hacer mucho

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu duda, en primer lugar necesitaríamos que adjuntaras tu código css para tener más información, no obstante si te refieres a los espacios en blanco que se quedan en ambos laterales de la página, se pueden corregir introduciendo las siguientes lineas arriba de tu código

```
<style>
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

posteriormente si quieres darle un margen a un div en concreto, bastaría con que modificaras el estilo de ese div, ejemplo

```
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-left:30px">
```